# No module named 'rest_frameworkoauth2_provider'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I am setting up a django rest api and need to integrate social login feature.I followed the following link
[Simple Facebook social Login using Django Rest Framework.](https://medium.com/@katherinekimetto/simple-facebook-social-login-using-django-rest-framework-e2ac10266be1)

After setting up all , when a migrate (7 th step :- python manage.py migrate
)  , getting the error ' ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_frameworkoauth2_provider'
' . Is there any package i missed? i cant figure out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have forgotten to add a comma between ‘rest_framework’ and ‘oauth2_provider’ probably in your INSTALLED_APPS setting

Comment: in step 9 , i am getting 404 error page in postman..why @lain Shelvington

Answer (score 1):

Your installed apps should look like below. In python if didn't add a comma between strings then python will concatenate them like `'a' 'b'` will become `ab`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'rest_framework',
    'oauth2_provider'
    # ...
]
```